# Use component with connect() - Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have a strange problem related to the function ‘connect’ and a presentational component

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import * as optionGroupActions from 'actions/optionGroupActions';
import OptionGroupForm from 'components/optionGroup/OptionGroupForm';

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    saveOptionGroup: (optionGroup) => {
      dispatch(optionGroupActions.fetchSaveOptionGroup(optionGroup));
    },
    onClickCancel: () => {
      ownProps.router.push('/product/options');
    }
  };
};

const OptionGroupAddContainer = connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(OptionGroupForm);

export default OptionGroupAddContainer;
```

This works but if I change the import with this

```
import { OptionGroupForm } from 'components’;
```

I got this error:

```
connect.js:57Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined
```

components/index.js looks like

```
// OptionGroups
import OptionGroupForm from 'components/optionGroup/OptionGroupForm';

export {
  OptionGroupForm
};
```

Comment: I got this error because I accidentally added parentheses after my class decorator: `@withRouter()` instead of `@withRouter`. [See more here.](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/387)

Answer (score 3):

if you want to `import` like below

```
import { OptionGroupForm } from 'components’;
```

you have to use `resolve` in your build process config file to define the `path` variable,

or you can just `import` it like below

```
import { OptionGroupForm } from './components’;
```

EDIT: Your components/index.js should look like below

```
import OptionGroupForm from './optionGroup/OptionGroupForm';

export {
  OptionGroupForm
};
```

Comment: I used to use this import { OptionGroupForm } from 'components’; in my other files... and it works correctly

Comment: i have edited my answer check it, you dont have to define path like it when you are in components folder "components/optionGroup/OptionGroupForm".
maybe that's why it was showing that error

Comment: you are welcome, can you mark my answer as a right answer if my answer helps you, so that other can get helps from it thanks

Comment: I tried.. I hoped that worked but I have the same problem... When I have updated my index.js, I have still the same problem. Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: on your main file you have imported like below right? import { OptionGroupForm } from 'components’; make sure you have put those curly braces when importing it to the main file

Comment: Yes I tried to use this `import { OptionGroupForm } from 'components’;` in my component file and I used this `import OptionGroupForm from './optionGroup/OptionGroupForm';

export {
  OptionGroupForm
};`in the index.js

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your build process, you may need to specify your import like this in order to have the source be treated as a relative path rather than an npm module name:

```
import { OptionGroupForm } from './components’;
```

Comment: I used to use this `import { OptionGroupForm } from 'components’;` in my other files... and it works correctly :-/